# I can't access an url with more than 2 nested url paths in my server

Tags: reactjs, laravel, url

I'm working in laravel react project such that there is only one route in laravel web routes:

```
Route::view('/{path?}/{path2?}/{path3?}/{path4?}/{path5?}/{path6?}/{path7?}/{path8?}/{path9?}', 'index');
```

and in the index view I uses an js file which control the react routes

There's a route which contains more than 2 nested url pahts

```
<Route path="/admin/dashboard/users" component={Dashboard} />
```

but I can't access it in the browser and

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

is written in the console

the same error appears in all 'more than two nested url path' routes in the form /path1/path2/path3/......

What is the problem?

and I'm sorry for my bad English